# keep rows in data that meet conditions based on previous rows

Tags: r, logic, subset

I am trying to write some code to only keep rows in my data frame that:

have the same ID but different Dates.

Below is my current and desired application date.

#### current

[image: current]

#### desired

[image: desired]

Comment: because that ID only appears once

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'ID', `filter` the IDs with number of distinct 'Date' are greater than 1

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(Date, na.rm = TRUE) > 1) %>%
    ungroup
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
subset(df1, ID %in% names(which(table(unique(df1[c('ID', 'Date')])$ID) > 1)))
```

Comment: Isn't the `n() > 1` redundant? You can't have `n_distinct(...) > 1` with 1 value.

Comment: @thelatemail you are right.  thanks